# How to pass a variable to a mapnik datasource class?

Tags: python, mapnik

Im newbie in python, so excuse me for this newbie question. I have a class and a function:

```
class Datasource(mapnik.PythonDatasource):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Datasource, self).__init__()

    def features(self, query):
        return mapnik.PythonDatasource.wkb_features(mvt)

def tileLayer(request, version, shapefile_id, zoom, x, y):
    mvt = requestHandler(request, zoom, x, y)

    datasource = mapnik.Python(factory='Datasource')
```

How can I pass the `mvt` variable to the `Datasource` class when calling `mapnik.Python(factory='Datasource')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional arguments to `mapnik.Python` method - they will be passed to datasource `__init__`:

```
mvt = requestHandler(request, zoom, x, y)
datasource = mapnik.Python(factory='Datasource', mvt=mvt)
```

add argument to `Datasource` class `__init__` method definition and use it to save `mvt` in class instance:

```
class Datasource(mapnik.PythonDatasource):
    def __init__(self, mvt):
        super(Datasource, self).__init__()
        self.mvt = mvt

    def features(self, query):
        return mapnik.PythonDatasource.wkb_features(self.mvt)
```